Converting weekly cumulative into monthly non-cumulative
I have this dataset here which cumulative weekly covid-19 death rates in Canada (scroll to bottom of page): https://health-infobase.canada.ca/covid-19/ . I want to convert this to monthly non-cumulative.
I download it in R (note that this is the death rate in the general population, not death rate of the infected population):
temp_file <- tempfile()
download.file(
    url = "https://health-infobase.canada.ca/src/data/covidLive/covid19-download.csv",
    destfile = temp_file
)

covid_data <- read.csv(temp_file)

I make this plot for the cumulative weekly death rate of different provinces:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales) 

ggplot(covid_data, aes(x = as.Date(date), y = ratedeaths, color = prname)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(
        x = "Date",
        y = "Death Rate",
        color = "Province"
    ) +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") + theme_bw() + ggtitle("Original Data: Cumulative Weekly")

I then made it non-cumulative weekly:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

covid_data <- covid_data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(prname) %>%
    arrange(date) %>%
    mutate(daily_death_rate = ratedeaths - lag(ratedeaths, default = first(ratedeaths))) %>%
    mutate(daily_death_rate = pmax(daily_death_rate, 0))


    
    ggplot(covid_data, aes(x = date, y = daily_death_rate, color = prname)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(
        x = "Date",
        y = "Daily Death Rate",
        color = "Province"
    ) +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") + theme_bw() + ggtitle("Transformed Data: Non-Cumulative Weekly")

I actually want this to be monthly averages, so I again transformed it to now non-cumulative monthly:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)  


covid_data_monthly <- covid_data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    mutate(year_month = floor_date(date, "month")) %>%
    group_by(prname) %>%
    arrange(date) %>%
    mutate(daily_death_rate = ratedeaths - lag(ratedeaths, default = first(ratedeaths))) %>%
    mutate(daily_death_rate = pmax(daily_death_rate, 0)) %>%
    group_by(prname, year_month) %>%
    summarise(
        monthly_avg_death_rate = mean(daily_death_rate, na.rm = TRUE),
        .groups = "drop"
    )

ggplot(covid_data_monthly, 
       aes(x = year_month, y = monthly_avg_death_rate, color = prname)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    labs(
        x = "Date",
        y = "Average Daily Death Rate",
        color = "Province"
    ) +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") + theme_bw() + ggtitle("Final Data: Non-Cumulative Monthly")

I am just wondering: Is this the correct way to make this conversion?

updated R code:
  library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(scales)
    library(lubridate)
    
    temp_file <- tempfile()
    download.file(
        url = "https://health-infobase.canada.ca/src/data/covidLive/covid19-download.csv",
        destfile = temp_file
    )
    covid_data <- read.csv(temp_file)
    
    # convert weekly rates to interpolated daily rates
    covid_data_daily <- covid_data %>%
        mutate(
            date = as.Date(date),
            # Use the provided weekly rate column
            weekly_rate = ratedeaths_last7
        ) %>%
        # create 7 rows for each week with daily rates
        group_by(prname) %>%
        arrange(date) %>%
        # expand each week into 7 days
        slice(rep(1:n(), each = 7)) %>%
        # adjust dates to spread across the week
        mutate(
            # subtract 6 days to get to start of week, then add row number within week
            actual_date = date - 6 + (row_number() - 1) %% 7,
            # convert weekly rate to daily rate
            daily_rate = weekly_rate / 7
        )
    
    # calculate monthly rates
    covid_data_monthly <- covid_data_daily %>%
        mutate(year_month = floor_date(actual_date, "month")) %>%
        group_by(prname, year_month) %>%
        # sum daily rates to get monthly rate
        summarise(
            monthly_death_rate = sum(daily_rate, na.rm = TRUE),
            .groups = "drop"
        )
    
    
    ggplot(covid_data_monthly, 
           aes(x = year_month, y = monthly_death_rate, color = prname)) +
        geom_line() +
        geom_point() +
        labs(
            x = "Date",
            y = "Monthly Death Rate per 100,000 population",
            color = "Province",
            title = "Monthly COVID-19 Death Rates by Province",
            subtitle = "Based on interpolated daily rates from weekly data"
        ) +
        scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
        theme_bw()


Welcome to SO! I see a few potential issues, which I'll put each its own comment. It's possible I'm not understanding the intent of the code correctly, though. Adding comments would make review much easier.


Your column daily_death_rate appears to actually be the weekly death rate. Also, why not just use the ratedeaths_last7 column from the original dataset rather than calculating it yourself?



The way you group weeks into months is problematic. For example, reporting week of May 2, 2020 will be counted as part of May, even though most of the reporting week (Sunday - Thursday) was in April and only two days (Friday, Saturday) were in May. One way to address this would be by interpolating daily data (i.e., making one row for each day of every week where the rate is 1/7 the weekly rate) and then summarizing. Not perfect, but likely more accurate.



When you summarize by month, you take the mean. This will give you the mean weekly death rate in that month, but if you want monthly death rate, you should instead take the sum. However, only do this if you address the issue in (2), because taking the sum rather than the mean will exacerbate the issue.


And also a question: What are you doing with pmax(daily_death_rate, 0)? Are there negative data?

thank you so much Eonema for your feedback!

pmax(daily_death_rate, 0) : this was just a safety check in case some negative numbers show up ...

Happy to help! I might suggest instead of that, adding a line stopifnot(all(covid_data$daily_death_rate >= 0)). If negative numbers show up, you probably have a problem somewhere that you should fix at the source, and this would let you know if there are any negative numbers.

thank you so much! I am working on summarizing your feedback! can you please write an answer if you have time?

I am almost done incorporating your feedback ... would you like to see my modified code based on your feedback?

Happy to look over it again if you'd like.

please see the updates!

As requested by OP, I'm putting my comments in an answer:
I see several potential issues in your code:

Your column daily_death_rate appears to actually be the weekly death rate. Also, why not just use the ratedeaths_last7 column from the original dataset rather than calculating it yourself?

The way you group weeks into months is problematic. For example, reporting week of May 2, 2020 will be counted as part of May, even though most of the reporting week (Sunday - Thursday) was in April and only two days (Friday, Saturday) were in May. One way to address this would be by interpolating daily data (i.e., making one row for each day of every week where the rate is 1/7 the weekly rate) and then summarizing. Not perfect, but likely more accurate.

When you summarize by month, you take the mean. This will give you the mean weekly death rate in that month, but if you want monthly death rate, you should instead take the sum. However, only do this if you address the issue in (2), because taking the sum rather than the mean will exacerbate the issue.

I might suggest that instead of changing all negative values to 0, adding a line stopifnot(all(covid_data$daily_death_rate >= 0)). If negative numbers show up, you probably have a problem somewhere that you should fix at the source, and this would let you know if there are any negative numbers.



thank you! I  will now post my updated code

@nov62024 Looks solid to me, though keep in mind I might have missed something! Nice use of slice, I wouldn't have thought of that.
